# How to move all files in dir to another, but copy latest?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find, backup

I'm trying to write a backup script that moves all files from a directory, but only copies the latest modified/newest file.

I'm running into some trouble where I'm not able to return the correct latest file, because I think I cannot get `find` or `ls` to list the files by modified, and also output just the filename. So my `$latestfile` ends up being a different file.

Help?

My current code:

```
# Primary Backup Location
BACKUP_LOCATION=/my/backup/dir

# List latest file
latestfile=$(find ${BACKUP_LOCATION} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort -nr | awk "NR==1,NR==1 {print $2}")

echo "Latest file is $latestfile"

# List all (EXCEPT LAST) files and get ready to Backup
echo "Backing up all files except last"
for file in $(find ${BACKUP_LOCATION} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f \! -name "$latestfile" -printf "%f\n" | sort -nr )
do
    echo $file
    #mv $file /some/target/dir/$file
done
```

Comment: Try this approach to find the latest file: https://askubuntu.com/a/61180/672946 You'll probably want to use `head -n 1` there at the end.

Comment: Also, if your `bash` has `extglob` set, you can simply move all files but the latest one like so: `mv /my/backup/dir/!($latestfile) /some/target/dir/`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having a real hard time finding out how to filter for just the base filename and the latest. Any idea how I can just get `filename.txt` rather than `/dir/path/filename.ext` as a result for latest file?

Comment: You could use `find` with a relative path instead of an absoulte one, such as `find .`

Comment: Thanks, but I eventually figured it out.
I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: rsync is prefered tool for backup

Comment: Preferred is relative, there is no standard for backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to make this work.
Here is the part of my backup script for this, hopefully someone may find it useful.

```
# Location to Backup from
BACKUP_TARGET="/my/dir/to/backup"
# Location to Backup to
BACKUP_LOCATION="/my/backup/store"

# List latest file
file_latest=$(find ${BACKUP_TARGET} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -n 1 | sed 's|.*/||' )
echo "Latest file is $file_latest"

# List the rest of files
file_rest_of_em=$(find ${BACKUP_TARGET} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f \! -name "$file_latest" | sed 's|.*/||' )

# make newlines the only separator
IFS=$'\n'

# Backup all previous Backups, MOVE ALL
echo "Backing up all files except Latest Backup..."
for file in $file_rest_of_em
do
    echo "Moving $file"
    mv -n ${BACKUP_TARGET}/$file $BACKUP_LOCATION/
done

# Backup Latest Backup, LEAVE COPY BEHIND
if [ -f "$BACKUP_LOCATION/$file_latest" ]; then
    echo "$file_latest (Latest Backup) already exists."
else
    echo "$file_latest (Latest Backup) does not exist."
    echo "Copying $file_latest..."
    cp -n --preserve=all ${BACKUP_TARGET}/$file_latest $BACKUP_LOCATION/
fi

# done with newline shenanegans
unset IFS
```

Thanks for your help @Panki